# How do you use a batch to modify certain values in a .txt file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a .txt file which contains 1 line in the following format:
XX-C-0001
I want to save a new file with the incremented number, like:
XX-C-0002

The Problem is, I dont know how to save the "0002" as a variable

Heres what i come up with:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=3" "delims=-" %%a in name.txt( 
'VER' 
) do ( 
set myvar=%%a 
) 
set /A var=%myvar%+1
>new_name.txt echo %var%
pause 
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `for` syntax (it's off at some points, but where did `'ver'` come from?)
To increase the number, you have to be a bit more creative because of the leading zeros. Put a `1` in front of it (make it `1000x`), then increase it and use just the last four characters for the result.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=3 delims=-" %%a in (name.txt) do set "myvar=1%%a" 
set /A myvar+=1
>new_name.txt echo XX-C-%myvar:~-4%
type new_name.txt
endlocal
```